# Auto responder email that sends out an application form and is able to send it back along with documents

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a client that has asked me to be able to have an application form sent to applicants via email as an an attachment.

Is it possible to have the applicant fill out a name and address send it to an email have them send it back after filling with documents attached.

HTML as follows

```
<form action="application.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br><br>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email"><br><br>
 <p>Once you have completed this form upload it here and along with your documents and click the button below</p><input type="file" name="SF 02A APPLICATION FORM">
 <button class="btn btn-green" type="button">Apply Here</button>
</form>
```

PHP below

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $attachment = $_FILES['SF 02A APPLICATION FORM'];

  // Validate the input and attachment

  // Send the auto response email
  $to = $name;
  $subject = 'Job Application';
  $message = 'Thank you for your interest in joining this great team! Below you will find an application form as an attachment for you to fill out please take your time in doing this, also along with the application you will need to send copies of your documentation to us to help speed up your application.
  If you have any issues concerning your application do not hesitate to contact us.';
  $headers = 'From: Admin <your.domain@website.co.uk>';
  
  $file_path = $attachment['assets/img/SF 02A APPLICATION FORM'];
  $file_name = $attachment['Application Form'];
  $file_type = $attachment['word-doc'];
  
  $attachment_data = file_get_contents($file_path);
  $base64_attachment = base64_encode($attachment_data);
  
  $boundary = md5(time());
  
  $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"" . $boundary . "\"\n";
  
  $message = "--" . $boundary . "\n";
  $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
  $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
  $message .= $message . "\n\n";
  
  $message .= "--" . $boundary . "\n";
  $message .= "Content-Type: " . $file_type . "; name=\"" . $file_name . "\"\n";
  $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file_name . "\"\n";
  $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
  $message .= $base64_attachment . "\n\n";
  $message .= "--" . $boundary . "--\n";
  
  // Send the email
  if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "Email sent successfully.";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to send email.";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: I am basically asking that when someone fills out a form online that an attachment gets sent with the auto reply with a link to upload the form and other documents when it is complete I have the email setup already I'm just struggling with the code to make this work.

Comment: I can't tell what exactly you are asking here. So you are sending a Word document as attachment, by the looks of it - and now, what? Not sure what exactly you want to happen next.